# Subscriptions are not showing up once IPA got created in iOS In App Purchase StoreKit2

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, storekit, storekit2

I have implemented In App Purchase using Apple's StoreKit framework. I have created a .storekit file inside Xcode and synced all the subscriptions from App Store Connect. When I do connect my device to Xcode and install the app, it retrieves all the subscriptions and am able to subscribe them as well. but when I do create an IPA and install the app in the same device no subscriptions are listed there and the storekit api returning zero number of products.

```
let storeProducts = try await Product.products(for: productIdToEmoji.keys)
```

this is the code to get the products. I have already checked the product identifiers, and the subscription are also in ready to submit stage in App Store Connect. I wonder what is the issue and how to fix them. and I am also assuming that by keeping storekit file in the project and syncing all the plans from App Store Connect should be able to go live as well.

Comment: A StoreKit file is only used for development. You should not ship a StoreKit file to the the App Store.

Comment: How can I retrieve the subscription details from App Store Connect without using store kit file then ? I suppose this Product API should return the subscription details  but it somehow not working.

Comment: You use store kit. The code in your app is the same. You just don't need a store kit file. The store kit file is used in development to "mock" the actual StoreKit responses so that you can test things more easily. When your app is released, the device will actually communicate with Apple's  servers to get product details.